# simplest way to call an external/public contrat function

Tags: solidity

Let's suppose i've deployed a smartcontract and let's suppose i have deleted the solidity source code on my computer.

- I know the deployed address
- I know a function signature

What is the simplest way to call this function ?

I have tried web3js code but in my opinion it it is a very complex way

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

Here is a basic web3js code.
My main problem is i do not know the full ABI. I only know my function's signature (name, arguments and return type)

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<myprojectid>")
const ABI = [ { "inputs": [ { ... 
const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, "0x<contract_address>");
instance.methods.the_function_i_want_to_call().call((err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It's pretty simple in web3.js, what exactly have you tried there which makes you think that "it is a very complex way"?

Comment: BTW, if you're asking for a simpler method, then you should obviously provide the method which you want to make simpler!

Comment: `My main problem is i do not know the full ABI`: 1. This is not a problem, because you don't need the entire ABI, just the part related to the specific function that you want to call. 2. Assuming that you have indeed considered this a problem, why did you ask for "a simpler solution" and not just "a solution"??? There is nothing to simplify here.

Comment: Because this code is not simple to my opinion

Comment: How else would you like it to be?

Comment: I cannot set my wallet account. It only works for view functions

Comment: Please make up your mind - are you having an actual problem in calling some function, or do you already know exactly how to do that and you are just looking for a simpler way?

Comment: What does "I cannot set my wallet account" even mean here???

Comment: The example i pasted in my edit shows a view function. That's mean this function does not write anything on the blockchain. If i call a smart-contract's function which write on the blockchain, i need a wallet and an account in order to pay gas. This is what i want to do and it is very complex for me with web3

Comment: If you unlock your account on the node that you're communicating with prior to executing the transaction, then it's pretty simple - you only need to replace the `.call` with `.send`. Of course, public nodes such as infura don't allow this option (obviously, since others will be able to send transactions from your unlocked account at will). And even on your private node, it is rather risky, as anyone hacking your node will be able to send transaction from your unlocked account will. What you need to do here, is sign the transaction with your private key and then send it.

Comment: This is not that complicated though. Any other web3 implementation (web3.py, web3j, etc) would require you to perform the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest without programming would be to use a wallet that supports interacting with a contract. It is possible to do that with Remix and Metamask.

To do so programmatically with the contract ABI use [@trufle/hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/hdwallet-provider) or [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/).

It can be done without the ABI take a look at libraries like [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi). Then add the encoded function call to `data` parameter for `sendTransaction`.